# Multithreaded socket programming in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-watchdog

I am working on client/server socket programming using python. I could set it up without any issue, but with threads, I am lost. I don't have a clue how to get that part done. I looked at the python documentation as well, but I could not find what I was expecting.

What I am trying to achieve is - Server is accepting the connection from the client as well as monitoring a directory for any file creation. I am trying to run both of them in parallel, but it didn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is server.py file

import socket               # Import socket module
import sys,os
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.challenger", "*.challenger"]

    def process(self, event):
        """
        event.event_type
            'modified' | 'created' | 'moved' | 'deleted'
        event.is_directory
            True
        event.src_path
            /home/abcd/Maildir/new/
        """
        # the file will be processed there
        print event.src_path, event.event_type  # print now only for degug

    def on_modified(self, event):
        self.process(event)
        flag = '1'
        print flag

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)

    def on_any_event(self,event):
        if event.event_type == 'created':
            send()


s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 12346                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
flag = '0'
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print 'Got connection from', addr

#   c.send('Thank you for connecting')
#   c.send(flag)        

    if __name__ == '__main__':

       args = sys.argv[1:]
       observer = Observer()
       observer.schedule(MyHandler(), path='/home/abcd/Maildir/new')
       observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
          time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
         observer.stop()

observer.join()


c.send(flag)
c.close()                # Close the connection
```

The code I posted is without threads because with thread it didn't work at all.

I am using watchdog to monitor /home/abcd/Maildir/new to monitor any new e-mail file created, and if it is created I want to send acknowledgement (flag, in this case) to the client that the e-mail has been received. Socket connection and Watchdog worked well individually, but I don't know why they wouldn't work together? :(

How can I put these methods in different threads so that they run parallelly? Thanks for your help.

EDIT: code after Craig's input:

```
import threading
import socket               # Import socket module
import sys,os
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

def send_message(conn, flag):
    conn.send(flag)


class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.challenger", "*.challenger"]

    def __init__(self, conn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.conn_list = conn

    def process(self, event):
        """
        event.event_type
            'modified' | 'created' | 'moved' | 'deleted'
        event.is_directory
            True
        event.src_path
            /home/abcd/Maildir/new/
        """
        print "I reached here too"
        time.sleep(5)
        print event.src_path, event.event_type  # print now only for degug

    def on_created(self, event):
        flag = '1'
        threads = [threading.Thread(target=send_message, args=(conn, flag)) for conn in self.conn_list]
        for t in threads:
            t.start()
        print "on_created"
        self.process(event)
        for t in threads:
            t.join()


from collections import deque
conn_list = deque()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
    host = socket.gethostname()  # Get local machine name
    port = 12346                # Reserve a port for your service.
    s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
    flag = '0'
    s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(conn_list), path='/home/abcd/Maildir/new/')
    observer.start()
    print "Before True"
while True:
     try:
        c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
        print 'Got connection from', addr
        conn_list.append(c)
        time.sleep(1)
        print "I started Observer"
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
        while conn_list:
            conn_list.pop().close()
        print "Connections closed"
        break

observer.join()
```

EDIT 2 :

When I send e-mail from client to server, I get the correct result first time but when I connect one more time, the output is weird ("In message" prints twice, flag value also prints twice and I get broken pipe error)

Modified Server.py after Craig's input:

```
import threading
import socket               # Import socket module
import sys,os
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler


def send_message(conn, flag):
    print "In message"
    conn.send(flag)
    print "flag"+flag

class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.challenger", "*.challenger"]

    def __init__(self, conn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.conn_list = conn

    def process(self, event):
        time.sleep(5)
        print "In process"
        print event.src_path, event.event_type  # print now only for degug

    def on_created(self, event):
        flag = '1'
        print "before process event"
        self.process(event)
        print "after process, before thread target"
        threads = [threading.Thread(target=send_message, args=(conn, flag)) for$
        flag = '0'
        for t in threads:
            t.start()
#        print "Before process(Event)"
#        self.process(event)
        print "after process event"
        for t in threads:
            t.join()

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()  # Get local machine name
port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
flag = '0'
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
print "flag before: "+flag

from collections import deque
conn_list = deque()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    observer = Observer()
    observer.start()
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(conn_list), path='/home/abcd/Maildir/new')
while True:
    try:
        c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
        print 'Got connection from', addr
        flag = '0'
        print flag
        conn_list.append(c)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
        while conn_list:
            conn_list.pop().close()
        print "Connections closed"
        break

observer.join()
```

Here's the output:

```
Got connection from ('72.123.27.223', 39844)
0
before process event
In process
/home/abcd/Maildir/new/1425403821.V801I2ac232cM275759.challenger created
after process, before thread target
In message
In message
flag1In message
 after process event

 flag1
Exception in thread Thread-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/paras/server42.py", line 11, in send_message
    conn.send(flag)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Here's my client.py - All I am trying to do is check e-mail latency from client to server and getting response back from the server.

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is client.py file
import sys,smtplib
import socket               # Import socket module
import threading,time
import urllib
import random
import datetime
#class myThread(threading.Thread):
#    def __init__ (self,name):
#        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
#   self.name=name

#    def run(self):
#        connection()    
#        print "Starting"+self.name

def connection():
    s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
    host = socket.gethostbyname('server.edu') # Get local machine name
    port = 12345                # Reserve a port for your service.
    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
#        print s.recv(1024)
        t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
        sendmail()
    t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
        print str(t1),str(t2) 
        print "Time taken to send e-mail from client to server: "+str(t2-t1)
        print "came back"
        flag = s.recv(1024)
        print flag
        if (flag=='1'):
            t3=datetime.datetime.now()   
        print "Time taken to receive response from server: "+str(t3-t2)
        s.close                     # Close the socket when done
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        s.close

def sendmail():
    fromaddr = 'xyz@gmail.com'

    toaddrs = 'email@server.edu'
    url = "http://www.google.com"
    seq = str(random.randint(1,9))
    msg = 'URL: '+ url  + '\n'+'SEQ:'+seq+'\n'
    print "In sendmail"
#print msg

# Credentials (if needed)
    username = 'xyz@gmail.com'
    password = 'somepassword'
#The actual mail send
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
#server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
    server.quit()
    print "email sent"
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connection()
```

Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't exactly do what you asked since the server doesn't send the data but I think it achieves what you want to do. You could pass along connection object so that you can send the flag to it from MyHandler.

```
class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    patterns = ["*.challenger", "*.challenger"]

    def __init__(self, conn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.conn_list = conn

    def process(self, event):
        time.sleep(5)
        print event.src_path, event.event_type  # print now only for degug

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)
        c = self.conn_list.pop()
        c.send('1')
        c.close()



s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname()  # Get local machine name
port = 12346                # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
flag = '0'
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.


from collections import deque
conn_list = deque()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    observer = Observer()
    observer.start()
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(conn_list), path='/home/abcd/Maildir/new')
while True:
    try:
        c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
        print 'Got connection from', addr
        conn_list.append(c)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
        while conn_list:
            conn_list.pop().close()
        print "Connections closed"
        break

observer.join()
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I modified my code and it worked to some extent. Now the problem is s.accept() being blocking call,
it does not let on_create() run for some reason. when I comment out s.accept(), Watchdog could run and detect changes
in the folder. How can I separate these two? such that server can handle connections as well as run monitor on folder?
should I make one of them run in background as a service?

Meanwhile, I've updated my question with new code.

Comment: No problem :). According to [the watchdog documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.observers.Observer) the observer runs in its own thread. It works concurrently for me, what exactly happens when a client is connected and a new file is created? On my machine it is able to 'process' the file while waiting for a new connection.

Comment: Thanks. I went through the documentation, but I guess it should be my client program that causes this error.. I've updated my question with error I get and the client code. Thanks again :)

Comment: Could you try changing s.close to s.close() in your client code?

Comment: Still the same error. On the third attempt, I get broken pipe error. Also, I don't understand why send_message and flag values are printed twice!

Comment: Sorry, I think i misunderstood your question earlier because I assumed you'd have multiple clients connected to the server at the same time. I modified my answer to just notify one client connection now and close the socket right after. Also, I believe it was printing twice because there were 2 connections in self.conn_list the second time you connected and the server attempted to send it to them both.